# Trying to use change() inside another change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use change() function in jquery in my script to change matiere list data when the user will chose niveau opion 
I tried to add another change() function inside the first change fucntion but it is not working it remove all the data from all selectbox
but when I use only the first change function it's working without a problem
Here is my form

```
  <form>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label class="purple">Cycle</label>
              <select id="cycle" required class="chosen form-control border-or" name="cycle"  >
              <option required selected disabled value="fail">Choix du cycle </option>
                </select>
                </div>
              </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="purple">Ecole</label>
          <select id="ecole" required class="chosen form-control border-or" name="ecole"  >
            <option required selected disabled value="fail">Choix de l'école </option>
            <option  required class="form-control " value= "elmanbaa" > EL MANBAA </option>
            <option  required class="form-control " value= "source" >LA SOURCE DE TETOUAN  </option>
            <option  required class="form-control " value= "ilm" > MANABIA AL ILM </option>

            </select>
            </div>
          </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
              <label class="purple">Matiere</label>
              <select required class="chosen form-control border-or"  id="matiere" name="matiere"  >
              <option required selected disabled value="fail">Choix de la matiere </option>

                </select>
                </div>
               </div>
            </form>
```

Here is my jquery script:

```
      <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

  $("#ecole").change(function () {
     switch($(this).val()) {
        case 'elmanbaa':
          $("#cycle").html("<option value='maternelle'>Maternelle</option>");

         $("#cycle").change(function () {
              switch($(this).val()) {
                      case 'maternelle':
                    $("#matiere").html("<option   value= "Français" > Français </option>");
                      break;

                  default:
                      $("#matiere").html("<option value=''>--Choix matiere--</option>");
              }
            });


          $("#niveau").html("<option value='mm'>Moyenne maternelle</option><option value='gm'>");

            break;
        default:
            $("#size").html("<option value=''>--select one--</option>");
     }
  });


});


</script>
```

Comment: [`.change(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/change/#change-handler) adds an event handler. It doesn't change anything...

Comment: @HereticMonkey  sorry what do you means?

Comment: When the `"#ecole"` element changes, and its value is `'elmanbaa'`, you add handler for the `"#cycle"` element's change event. When the `"#cycle"` element changes later, the code in that function will fire, possibly multiple times, depending on how often the `"#ecole"` element was changed to `'elmanbaa'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.append()` to append element via dom instead of `.html()`. 

In following snippet, you can check for it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ecole").change(function () {
      console.log("#ecle", $('#ecole').val())
      switch($(this).val()) {
        case 'elmanbaa':
          $("#cycle").append("<option value='maternelle'>Maternelle</option>");   //Use append instead of html();

          $("#cycle").change(function () {
            console.log("#cycle", $('#cycle').val())
            switch($(this).val()) {
              case 'maternelle':
              $("#matiere").append("<option   value='Français'> Français </option>");
              break;

              default:
              $("#matiere").append("<option value=''>--Choix matiere--</option>");
              break;
            }
          });


          $("#niveau").append("<option value='mm'>Moyenne maternelle</option><option value='gm'>");

          break;
          default:
          $("#size").html("<option value=''>--select one--</option>");
        }
      });


  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="purple">Cycle</label>
        <select id="cycle" required class="chosen form-control border-or" name="cycle"  >
          <option required selected disabled value="fail">Choix du cycle </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="purple">Ecole</label>
        <select id="ecole" required class="chosen form-control border-or" name="ecole"  >
          <option required selected disabled value="fail">Choix de l'école </option>
          <option  required class="form-control " value= "elmanbaa" > EL MANBAA </option>
          <option  required class="form-control " value= "source" >LA SOURCE DE TETOUAN  </option>
          <option  required class="form-control " value= "ilm" > MANABIA AL ILM </option>

        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="purple">Matiere</label>
        <select required class="chosen form-control border-or"  id="matiere" name="matiere"  >
          <option required selected disabled value="fail">Choix de la matiere </option>

        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You can also check this code and verify it.

Comment: Glad to know that ... Welcome